# DB2 Case Sensitivity

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I'm having great difficultly making my DB2 (AS/400) queries case insensitive.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM NameTable
WHERE LastName = 'smith'
```

Will return no results, but the following returns 1000's of results:

```
SELECT *
FROM NameTable
WHERE LastName = 'Smith'
```

I've read of putting SortSequence/SortType into your connection string but have had no luck... anyone have exepierence with this?

Edit:

Here's the stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE CR CURSOR FOR
SELECT  T . ID ,
    T . LASTNAME ,
    T . FIRSTNAME ,
    T . MIDDLENAME ,
    T . STREETNAME || ' ' || T . ADDRESS2 || ' ' || T . CITY || ' ' || T . STATE || ' ' || T . ZIPCODE AS ADDRESS ,
    T . GENDER ,
    T . DOB ,
    T . SSN ,
    T . OTHERINFO ,
    T . APPLICATION
FROM
    ( SELECT R . * , ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( ) AS ROW_NUM
    FROM CPSAB32.VW_MYVIEW
    WHERE R . LASTNAME = IFNULL ( @LASTNAME , LASTNAME )
    AND R . FIRSTNAME = IFNULL ( @FIRSTNAME , FIRSTNAME )
    AND R . MIDDLENAME = IFNULL ( @MIDDLENAME , MIDDLENAME )
    AND R . DOB = IFNULL ( @DOB , DOB )
    AND R . STREETNAME = IFNULL ( @STREETNAME , STREETNAME )
    AND R . CITY = IFNULL ( @CITY , CITY )
    AND R . STATE = IFNULL ( @STATE , STATE )
    AND R . ZIPCODE = IFNULL ( @ZIPCODE , ZIPCODE )
    AND R . SSN = IFNULL ( @SSN , SSN )
    FETCH FIRST 500 ROWS ONLY )
AS T
WHERE ROW_NUM <= @MAXRECORDS
OPTIMIZE FOR 500 ROW ;

OPEN CR ;
RETURN ;
```

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is that you are using R as an alias in your FROM clause for all the values but you are not declaring the alias R after FROM CPSAB32.VW_MYVIEW

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not do this:

```
WHERE lower(LastName) = 'smith'
```

If you're worried about performance (i.e. the query not using an index), keep in mind that DB2 has function indexes, which you can read about [here](http://ibmsystemsmag.blogs.com/db2utor/2007/11/db2-9-index-wit.html). So essentially, you can create an index on `upper(LastName)`.

**EDIT**
To do the debugging technique I discussed in the comments, you could do something like this:

```
create table log (msg varchar(100, dt date);
```

Then in your SP, you can insert messages to this table for debugging purposes:

```
insert into log (msg, dt) select 'inside the SP', current_date from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Then after the SP runs, you can select from this log table to see what happened.

Comment: @dcp I've tried that before but it typically returns this message ERROR [HY000] [IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL0255 - Function not supported for query.

Comment: @mint - Hmm, lower seems to be a pretty standard DB2 function, I remember using it as far back as the late 1990's. Here's a reference: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_bif_lower.htm  If your DB doesn't support lower/upper, it must be very old indeed.

Comment: @dcp Well, I can run the straight sql of it fine.  But in my application I call a stored procedure and then it seems to flop... no idea why!

Comment: @mint - Tip: one technique I use to debug stored procedures is to create a temp table and insert messages to it. Then you can see what's going on. This is useful if you don't have the ability to step through the code in some debugger (I'm not sure what tools you have).

Comment: @mint - can you post your SP?

Comment: @mint - See my latest edit for an example of the debugging technique I described.

Comment: For those who want to accomplish case-insensitive queries that benefit from an index in DB2 LUW, you can do it with a generated column and an alternate index as described here: [http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0712stolze/#]

Comment: Can this be done with a setting, too? I have too many queries to change them all. Every text I ever compare is supposed to be case insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

If you want case-insensitive in your procedure, try using this option in it:

```
SET OPTION SRTSEQ = *LANGIDSHR ;
```

You should also create an index to support it for performance. Create the index when you have `*LANGIDSHR` as a connection attribute, and the shared-weight index should then be available to later jobs. (There are various ways to get the appropriate setting into effect.)

`*LANGIDSHR` relates to the language-ID for your jobs. Characters in the character set that might be considered as "equals", such as 'A' and 'a' or 'ü' and 'u', should be given equal weights (shared) and so select together.

Comment: ...stupid question: Where and when can I execute this statement?

Comment: This is for embedded SQL, it has to be the first SQL statement in the program, it is not an executable statement. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47164079/2296441) for more details if you are not programming in RPG or COBOL.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar when I wanted a case insensitive search. I used `UPPER(mtfield) = 'SEARCHSTRING'`. I know this works.

Answer (score -1):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47181640/5507619

## Database setting

There is a database config setting you can set at [database creation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/r0050489.html). It's based on unicode, though.

```
CREATE DATABASE yourDB USING COLLATE UCA500R1_S1
```

> The default Unicode Collation Algorithm is implemented by the UCA500R1 keyword without any attributes. Since the default UCA cannot simultaneously encompass the collating sequence of every language supported by Unicode, optional attributes can be specified to customize the UCA ordering. The attributes are separated by the underscore (_) character. The UCA500R1 keyword and any attributes form a UCA collation name.
>
> The Strength attribute determines whether accent or case is taken into account when collating or comparing text strings. In writing systems without case or accent, the Strength attribute controls similarly important features.
>   The possible values are: primary (1), secondary (2), tertiary (3), quaternary (4), and identity (I). To ignore:
>
> - accent and case, use the primary strength level
> - case only, use the secondary strength level
> - neither accent nor case, use the tertiary strength level
>
> Almost all characters can be distinguished by the first three strength levels, therefore in most locales the default Strength attribute is set at the tertiary level. However if the Alternate attribute (described below) is set to shifted, then the quaternary strength level can be used to break ties among white space characters, punctuation marks, and symbols that would otherwise be ignored. The identity strength level is used to distinguish among similar characters, such as the MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL A character (U+1D41A) and the MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL A character (U+1D44E).
>
> Setting the Strength attribute to higher level will slow down text string comparisons and increase the length of the sort keys.
>   Examples:
>
> - UCA500R1_S1 will collate "role" = "Role" = "rôle"
> - UCA500R1_S2 will collate "role" = "Role" < "rôle"
> - UCA500R1_S3 will collate "role" < "Role" < "rôle"

This worked for me. As you can see, ..._S2 ignores case, too.

Using a [newer standard version](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/r0050489.html), it should look like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE yourDB USING COLLATE CLDR181_S1
```

[Collation keywords](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/r0050489.html#d188313e1071):
`UCA400R1` = Unicode Standard 4.0 = CLDR version 1.2
`UCA500R1` = Unicode Standard 5.0 = CLDR version 1.5.1
`CLDR181` = Unicode Standard 5.2 = CLDR version 1.8.1

If your database is already created, there is supposed to be a way to [change the setting](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023593.html).

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD( 'UPDATE DB CFG USING DB_COLLNAME UCA500R1_S1 ' );
```

I do have problems executing this, but for all I know it is supposed to work.

## Generated table row

Other options are e.g. [generating a upper case row](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0712stolze/index.html):

```
CREATE TABLE t (
   id          INTEGER  NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
   str         VARCHAR(500),
   ucase_str   VARCHAR(500)  GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( UPPER(str) )
)@

INSERT INTO t(id, str)
VALUES ( 1, 'Some String' )@

SELECT * FROM t@

ID          STR                                  UCASE_STR
----------- ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------
          1 Some String                          SOME STRING

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: OP specifically indicated AS400, only the Generated table row portion of this answer is applicable.

Comment: You can have the access needed for a `CREATE DATABASE` on an AS400 machine. If you want all your querys to be case insensitive, you will need to set up your database accordingly. There are workarounds like the generated uppercase or using UPPER(...) in all of your statements. But of course you need to have admin access to the DB2 server if you want to change behaviour like case insensitivity. Sorry for expecting that.

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE` has not been available for `IBM i` since before v5r4. Database tables are generally created with a default CCSID based on the system CCSID. That is generally sufficient. You can override that CCSID on table creation.

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE` was replaced by `CREATE SCHEMA` as that is really what `CREATE DATABASE` actually did. DB2 on IBM i works a little different from PC or Linux databases that are not integrated into the OS. The whole machine is the database, and a program can access any database table anywhere on the box. Creating a second database doesn't make any sense in the context of IBM i because there isn't an independent database object. Maybe an equivalent would be to create a separate LPAR, but that is more of a new server instance.

Comment: I don't know about the specifics on your machine, I'm afraid. I would expect `CREATE SCHEMA` to have a similar option, though. I don't know. What I do know is: Yes, creating a second database does not make sense. Creating it, exporting the data from the old, importing it in the new, and deleting the old does make sense. At least it did for us, as that's what we did. I hoped the experience would be helpful in this case, too.

Comment: No, `CREATE SCHEMA` does not specify CCSID or sort sequence on IBM i. Tables are created with the system default CCSID unless specified otherwise on table creation. Character values are automatically converted on write from the job CCSID to the column CCSID and vice versa on read. And sort sequence is specified at the job or connection level. DB2 for i figures it out from there.